# How to check if device is supports in-app billing v3 in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

i wanna make an in-app purchase app. I have a code.And i have google play console all set. But id doesn't work.It's giving me this error :
"IabResult: Error checking for billing v3 support. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)" 
So i wanna check if my device is supports in-app billing v3. Here is my code:

```
package com.khabuko.dtv;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.khabuko.dtv.util.IabHelper;
import com.khabuko.dtv.util.IabResult;
import com.khabuko.dtv.util.Inventory;
import com.khabuko.dtv.util.Purchase;

public class InAppBillingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG =
        "InAppBilling";
IabHelper mHelper;
static final String ITEM_SKU = "com.khabuko.item";

private Button clickButton;
private Button buyButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_app_billing);

    buyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
    buyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buyClick(v);
        }
    });
    clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    clickButton.setEnabled(false);
    String base64EncodedPublicKey =
            "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAn+naZOOOHNVdP0zQMkeX5mFwBb9BU78cg4oqAxtY8gaMMuEHAaHBwU7yXW6zVh9uTof23SO4GzxTJcIPXCeTyMFmcoFkNvPtqZSFqYcqA5M8Ief0tzpXr81aLEe0lxSy/t3VTN29UA+AaXjt3bvsDXQQPUQXr1HEONfix6TsudI6SCILftZTMIfRZYfOU+0OJdi7J8uDkU2TBjz40UhGc4SWmCoANXVM5yjZ8w4jspXXmej7pP52NMb5nAlK5NrAgIEjHhSDrf8Sl0DhNwLTJM7e2yOWOPt/MvdDsQo1ensm2sSH0jwn1K04RVC8AIGPqtzxLZgP+Ysby0HKpMSU3wIDAQAB";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                                       Log.d(TAG,"45-46");
                                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                                                   result);
                                       } else {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                       }
                                   }
                               });
}

public void buttonClicked (View view)
{
    clickButton.setEnabled(false);
    buyButton.setEnabled(true);
}

public void buyClick(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }else {
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            return;
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            consumeItem();
            buyButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
};
public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    clickButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    // handle error
                }
            }
        };

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-app-billing availability is checked in `IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener()`.

But you have to wait some time after creating new SKUs. Any modification in Google Console doesn't happen immediately.

Comment: Thank you. But i already figured it out. Now can i ask you another question? Anyway question is how to get receipt of each purchase and send it to server?

Comment: It's better to ask a new question, check https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases

Comment: Yeah it's better but i don't have permission to ask another question.Anyway i solved the problem thank you for your concern :D